# Compiler doesn't pick up typeclass for the polymorphic constant value

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm new to Haskell, so forgive me in advance.

Why doesn't the following haskell code compile?

It seems like the compiler somehow fails to see that the type of the expression  `(maxBound :: a)` is `a` which has an `Enum` instance provided, not some `type variable ‘a0’` which is `ambiguous`.

```hs
class (Enum a, Bounded a) => SafeEnum a where
  ssucc :: a -> a
  ssucc x = if (fromEnum x) < (fromEnum (maxBound :: a)) then succ x else minBound

  spred :: a -> a
  spred x = if (fromEnum x) > (fromEnum (minBound :: a)) then pred x else maxBound
```

```
Stepik.hs:3:32: error:
    • Could not deduce (Enum a0) arising from a use of ‘fromEnum’
      from the context: SafeEnum a
        bound by the class declaration for ‘SafeEnum’
        at Stepik.hs:(1,1)-(6,82)
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Enum Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
        instance Enum Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
        instance Enum () -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
        ...plus six others
```

Comment: Not going to put as an answer, because I don't understand all the ins and outs (someone else can explain it all, who really understands it!) - but it works if you enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, even though type variables are scoped from the class being defined to the type signatures of the class's methods (i.e., the `a` in `class SafeEnum a` is the same `a` as the `a` in `ssucc :: a -> a`), they are **not** scoped from the type signatures of the methods to the method bodies, so in the expression `maxBound :: a` in the bodies of your functions `ssucc` and `spred`, the `a` has nothing to do with the `a` in the type signatures for those functions.

You can enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

after which the class definition will type check.

Note that this extension only applies to "normal" function declarations if you use the `forall` keyword.  So, outside of a class definition, you'd need to enable this extension *and* write:

```
ssucc :: forall a. a -> a 
ssucc x = ... maxBound :: a ...
```

or actually:

```
ssucc :: forall a. (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
ssucc x = ... maxBound :: a ...
```

but the rules are different inside a `class` clause.

See [the GHC docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-ScopedTypeVariables) for details.

Comment: And it works! Thank you! This behaviour seemed so natural that I couldn't guess it's not there by default...

Comment: @AntonSavelyev I get the feeling it's not there by default to prevent unwanted behavior in situations where you expect the type variables to be separate. For example, if you define multiple toplevel functions that all use `a`, you expect them to be different `a`'s. Similarly, if you define multiple functions in a `let ... in` that all use `a`, you probably don't want them to all mean the same `a`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this line to the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

Without this extension turned on, `maxBound :: a` does not refer to the same `a` as in the class.

Essentially, in standard Haskell, each type signature has its own type variables, which are independent from any other variable. For instance, this code

```
foo :: [a] -> Int
foo xs = length ys
   where
   ys :: [a]
   ys = xs
```

*fails*, since `ys :: [a]` really means `ys :: [b]` with an independent variable `b`, and `ys = xs` does not produce a `[b]`.

With the extension turned on, this compiles:

```
foo :: forall a . [a] -> Int
foo xs = length ys
   where
   ys :: [a]
   ys = xs
```

Arguably, there should be a different default, e.g. the extension should be on by default. Alternatively, GHC should hint at turning the extension on when the same `a` is used twice, since often that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @chi, it is up to the point. I just marked Another answer accepted as it's more elaborate.