# Haskell - How to use a type-parameter specified in type-signature in the function body?

Tags: haskell

I have the following heapsort code.

```
heapsort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
heapsort xs = Heap.toList (Heap.fromList $ xs :: Heap.MinHeap a)
```

This does not compile with the following error -

```
mergeLists.hs:32:28: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘a’
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        an expression type signature:
          forall a1. Heap.MinHeap a1
        at mergeLists.hs:32:50-63
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          heapsort :: forall a. Ord a => [a] -> [a]
        at mergeLists.hs:31:1-33
      Expected type: Heap.MinHeap a1
        Actual type: Heap.Heap Heap.MinPolicy a
    • In the first argument of ‘Heap.toList’, namely
        ‘(Heap.fromList $ xs :: Heap.MinHeap a)’
      In the expression:
        Heap.toList (Heap.fromList $ xs :: Heap.MinHeap a)
      In an equation for ‘heapsort’:
          heapsort xs = Heap.toList (Heap.fromList $ xs :: Heap.MinHeap a)
    • Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a] (bound at mergeLists.hs:32:10)
        heapsort :: [a] -> [a] (bound at mergeLists.hs:32:1)
   |
32 | heapsort xs = Heap.toList (Heap.fromList $ xs :: Heap.MinHeap a)
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I think this is because `a` in function body is not the same as `a` in the signature of the function. For example, if I enable partial type signatures and do

```
heapsort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
heapsort xs = Heap.toList (Heap.fromList $ xs :: Heap.MinHeap _)
```

the code compiles with the following warning (but no error).

```
λ> :load mergeLists
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( mergeLists.hs, interpreted )

mergeLists.hs:32:63: warning: [-Wpartial-type-signatures]
    • Found type wildcard ‘_’ standing for ‘a’
      Where: ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 heapsort :: forall a. Ord a => [a] -> [a]
               at mergeLists.hs:31:1-33
    • In an expression type signature: Heap.MinHeap _
      In the first argument of ‘Heap.toList’, namely
        ‘(Heap.fromList $ xs :: Heap.MinHeap _)’
      In the expression:
        Heap.toList (Heap.fromList $ xs :: Heap.MinHeap _)
    • Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a] (bound at mergeLists.hs:32:10)
        heapsort :: [a] -> [a] (bound at mergeLists.hs:32:1)
   |
32 | heapsort xs = Heap.toList (Heap.fromList $ xs :: Heap.MinHeap _)
   |                                                               ^
Ok, one module loaded.
```

So, how do I make this work with using partial type signatures feature? In general, how do I use a type-parameter from function's signature in the function's definition?

Comment: There was [a similar question very recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230741/compiler-doesnt-pick-up-typeclass-for-the-polymorphic-constant-value) - does enabling `ScopedTypeVariables` solve your problem as well?

Comment: @RobinZigmond No, starting ghci with `ghci -XScopedTypeVariables` does not fix the error.

Comment: `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` doesn't help either.

Comment: `ScopedTypeVariables` only take action if you explicitly quantify the variables, i.e. you need to make the signature `heapsort :: ∀ a . Ord a => [a] -> [a]`. You may also write `forall` instead of `∀`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I thought `∀` required `-XUnicodeSyntax` to work. In any case I would be fairly sure that `forall a.` is more common than `∀ a.` - so that would make `heapsort :: forall a. Ord a => [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: @bradrn I don't doubt that `forall` is more common, just I prefer the Unicode version.

Comment: I didn't know `forall` is a language feature. Yes, `forall` in the type-signature coupled with `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` removes the error.

Comment: You don't actually need to give the type signature at all in this case, right? Simply `heapsort = Heap.toList . Heap.fromList` should be all you need, and type inference handles the rest.

Comment: @Kakaji Yes, `forall` is indeed a language feature - something like `a -> a` is equivalent within GHC to `forall a. a -> a`. It's enabled by extensions such as `-XExplicitForall`, `-XScopedTypeVariables` and `-XRankNTypes`. That last extension in particular is very common in advanced Haskell: if you haven't heard of it yet, I would recommend looking it up - it's very interesting!

Comment: @amalloy Heap.fromList has to know if you need a MinHeap or a MaxHeap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you can do this using the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension.  This allows type variables used in function bodies to refer to the same variables used in the functions' signatures, but you have to "opt in" using the `forall` keyword:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import qualified Data.Heap as Heap

heapsort :: forall a . (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
heapsort xs = Heap.toList (Heap.fromList xs :: Heap.MinHeap a)
```

In this particular case, you could do it without any extension by specializing either `Heap.fromList` or `Heap.toList` to `MinHeap`.  For example:

```
heapsort' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
heapsort' = Heap.toList . minHeapFromList
  where minHeapFromList :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Heap.MinHeap a
        minHeapFromList = Heap.fromList
```

Here, the `a` type variables in the signatures for `heapsort'` and `minHeapFromList` are unrelated but, of course, they unify in the body for `heapsort'`.